# Bounded and Convergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Every convergent sequence is bounded.
and Not bounded implies Not convergent.

So what about the sequence 1/n , it does converge but isn't bounded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *sequence* $\frac1n$ is bounded and converges to $0$ as $n$ grows.

The corresponding *series*, in other words the *sequence* $\sum_{i = 1}^n\frac1i$, is unbounded and diverges (to $\infty$) as $n$ grows.

Comment: But how is the sequence 1/n bounded ? I mean this is the definition for boundedness - The sequence (xn) is bounded if there exists M > 0
such that |xn| ≤ M for all n ∈ N.
Otherwise (xn) is called unbounded (not bounded) ; How does 1/n fit into it ?

Comment: $|1/n |\le 1$ for all $n$

Comment: Oh well yes ! All right ! Thanks